# Button Message box, only allowing numerical values

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I'm creating a batch file that will run a VBScript as part of it, this script will open an Internet Explorer message box containing only clickable buttons, the problem i have is that i cannot enter a non numeric value for the button to output when it is clicked

it is based off of this template https://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_ui_buttons.php#InternetExplorer

when the script is run, the Internet Explorer button box will appear and nothing happens when i select the button for TC01 but the script will output a 2 when the button for TC02 is selected and 0322538 for when the button named TC03 is selected

I need each of the buttons to output a string when they are selected

```
' Create an IE object
Set objIE = CreateObject( "InternetExplorer.Application" )
' specify some of the IE window's settings
objIE.Navigate "about:blank"
sTitle="Make your choice " & String( 80, "." ) 'Note: the String( 80,".") is to push "Internet Explorer" string off the window
objIE.Document.title = sTitle
objIE.MenuBar        = False
objIE.ToolBar        = False
objIE.AddressBar     = false
objIE.Resizable      = False
objIE.StatusBar      = False
objIE.Width          = 250
objIE.Height         = 500
' Center the dialog window on the screen
With objIE.Document.parentWindow.screen
    objIE.Left = (.availWidth  - objIE.Width ) \ 2
    objIE.Top  = (.availHeight - objIE.Height) \ 2
End With
' Wait till IE is ready
Do While objIE.Busy
    WScript.Sleep 200
Loop


' Insert the HTML code to prompt for user input
objIE.Document.body.innerHTML = "<div align=""center"">" & vbcrlf _
                              & "<p><input type=""hidden"" id=""OK"" name=""OK"" value=""0"">" _
                              & "<input type=""submit"" value="" TC01 "" onClick=""VBScript:OK.value=EXT1GBMW0151315""></p>" _
                              & "<input type=""submit"" value="" TC02 "" onClick=""VBScript:OK.value=2""></p>" _
                              & "<input type=""submit"" value="" TC03 "" onClick=""VBScript:OK.value=0322538""></p>" _
```

the rest of the code is identical to the template i have used

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the summary of changes is:

1:

```
Dim objIE, sTitle, iErrorNum, myVal 'add myVal declaration
```

2 (use 444 as a placeholder switch value that will be processed below):

```
& "<input type=""submit"" value="" TC01 "" onClick=""VBScript:OK.value=444""></p>" _
```

3 (assign myVal to your desired output, save the button value to retVal, check it and output the correct final value as the IEButtons response):

```
myVal = "EXT1GBMW0151315"
Dim retVal
retVal = CStr(objIE.Document.all.OK.value)
If retVal = "444" Then
    IEButtons = myVal
Else
    IEButtons = CStr(objIE.Document.all.OK.value)
End If
```

Final block working to return your desired value for TC01:

```
 ' Save this code as IEButtonsDemo.vbs
 WScript.Echo IEButtons()

 Function IEButtons()
     ' This function uses Internet Explorer to create a dialog.
     Dim objIE, sTitle, iErrorNum, myVal
    'Create an IE object
    Set objIE = CreateObject( "InternetExplorer.Application" )
    ' specify some of the IE window's settings
    objIE.Navigate "about:blank"
    sTitle="Make your choice " & String( 80, "." ) 'Note: the String( 80,".") is to push "Internet Explorer" string off the window
    objIE.Document.title = sTitle
    objIE.MenuBar        = False
    objIE.ToolBar        = False
    objIE.AddressBar     = false
    objIE.Resizable      = False
    objIE.StatusBar      = False
    objIE.Width          = 250
    objIE.Height         = 500
    ' Center the dialog window on the screen
    With objIE.Document.parentWindow.screen
       objIE.Left = (.availWidth  - objIE.Width ) \ 2
       objIE.Top  = (.availHeight - objIE.Height) \ 2
    End With
    ' Wait till IE is ready
    Do While objIE.Busy
        WScript.Sleep 200
    Loop



    ' Insert the HTML code to prompt for user input
    objIE.Document.body.innerHTML = "<div align=""center"">" & vbcrlf _
                              & "<p><input type=""hidden"" id=""OK"" name=""OK"" value=""0"">" _
                              & "<input type=""submit"" value="" TC01 "" onClick=""VBScript:OK.value=444""></p>" _
                              & "<input type=""submit"" value="" TC02 "" onClick=""VBScript:OK.value=2""></p>" _
                              & "<input type=""submit"" value="" TC03 "" onClick=""VBScript:OK.value=0322538""></p>" _
                              & "<p><input type=""hidden"" id=""Cancel"" name=""Cancel"" value=""0"">" _
                              & "<input type=""submit"" id=""CancelButton"" value=""       Cancel       "" onClick=""VBScript:Cancel.value=-1""></p></div>"

    ' Hide the scrollbars
    objIE.Document.body.style.overflow = "auto"
    ' Make the window visible
    objIE.Visible = True
    ' Set focus on Cancel button
    objIE.Document.all.CancelButton.focus


    'CAVEAT: If user click red X to close IE window instead of click cancel, an error will occur.
    '        Error trapping Is Not doable For some reason
    On Error Resume Next
    Do While objIE.Document.all.OK.value = 0 and objIE.Document.all.Cancel.value = 0
        WScript.Sleep 200
        iErrorNum=Err.Number
        If iErrorNum <> 0 Then    'user clicked red X (or alt-F4) to close IE window
            IEButtons = 0
            objIE.Quit
            Set objIE = Nothing
            Exit Function
        End if
    Loop
    On Error Goto 0

    objIE.Visible = False

    ' Read the user input from the dialog window
    myVal = "EXT1GBMW0151315"
    Dim retVal
    retVal = CStr(objIE.Document.all.OK.value)
    If retVal = "444" Then
        IEButtons = myVal
    Else
        IEButtons = CStr(objIE.Document.all.OK.value)
    End If    
    ' Close and release the object
    objIE.Quit
    Set objIE = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: See my edit: `If retVal = "444" Then` <--This should be your check for retVal so the other buttons return the correct values. good luck